# discord.js v13.6.0 create and send server invite

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord, discord.js

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createInvite') ( djs v13.6.0 )

```
client.on("guildCreate", message => {

  let invite = message.channel.createInvite(
     {
       maxAge: 10 * 60 * 1000,
       maxUses: 0
     }
  )

  console.log(`${invite}`);
})
```

Comment: What do you get when you log `message.channel` or `message` to the console? This should be done before you try to define `invite`.

Comment: `Guild` doesn't have a `channel` property and is hence `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

When the `guildCreate` event is fired, a `Guild` object is passed into the callback, not a `Mesasge` object. So, since an invite is bound to a channel, you will need to get a channel first.
This might look like:

```js
client.on('guildCreate', (guild) => {
    // if you want an actual channel, you can put that here.
    const randomChannel = guild.channels.cache.random();

    console.log(randomChannel.createInvite(
        {
            maxAge: 10 * 60 * 1000,
            maxUses: 0
        },  
    ));
});
```